# CSS Flexbox group 2 flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to learn Flexbox and I'm stuck with a layout I want to create.

On mobile I have the following layout:

[image: Mobile layout]

Is it possible to get the following layout on desktop?

[image]

The code:

```css
.wrapper {  
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper > article { 
    flex: 3 66%;
  }
  .wrapper > aside {
    flex: 1 33%;
  }
}


/* rest of styling */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
article {
  height: 100px;
}
aside {
  height: 62px;
}

.article1 {
  background-color: Crimson;
}
.article2 {
  background-color: DarkCyan;
}
aside {
  background-color: DimGray;
}
header {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>header</h1>
  </header>
  <article class="article1">
    <h1>Article 1</h1>
  </article>
  <aside class="aside1">
    <h1>aside 1</h1>
  </aside>
  <article class="article2">
    <h1>Article 2</h1>
  </article>
  <aside class="aside2">
    <h1>aside 2</h1>
   </aside>
 </div>
```

Should I group the two aside flex items? (is it even possible?) Or should I use columns instead of rows?

Comment: This seems to be the similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383140/making-two-adjacent-elements-behave-like-a-single-element?noredirect=1#comment81754008_47383140

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirements, no fixed height, this can't be done with `flexbox` alone.

You either need to use script, which could move some elements on resize, like in this answer, [re-order `flexbox` item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41920277/2827823), or as in below sample, combining `flexbox` with `float`

```css
.wrapper {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.aside1 { order: 2; }
.aside2 { order: 4; }
.article1 { order: 1; }  
.article2 { order: 3; }  

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {  
    display: block;  
  }
  aside { float: right; width: 33.33%; }
  article { float: left; width: 66.66%; }  
}


/* rest of styling */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
article {
  height: 100px;
}
aside {
  height: 62px;
}
.article1 {
  background-color: Crimson;
}
.article2 {
  background-color: DarkCyan;
}
aside {
  background-color: DimGray;
}
header {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>header</h1>
  </header>

  <aside class="aside1">
    <h1>aside 1</h1>
  </aside>
  <article class="article1">
    <h1>Article 1</h1>
  </article>

  <aside class="aside2">
    <h1>aside 2</h1>
  </aside>
  <article class="article2">
    <h1>Article 2</h1>
  </article>
 </div>
```

---

Updated with a 2:nd sample after a comment

If you want to go with `flexbox` alone, and no script, the `order` property will make it easy to sort the elements but you'll need a inner wrapper with a fixed height

You can of course move the `header` outside the wrapper as well, though I guess you want them all in one container

```css
.innerwrapper {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header, .innerwrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
}
.innerwrapper > * {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .innerwrapper {
    height: 220px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  article {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  aside {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .aside1 { order: 3; }
  .aside2 { order: 4; }
  .article2 { order: 2; }  
}


/* rest of styling */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
article {
  height: 100px;
}
aside {
  height: 62px;
}
.article1 {
  background-color: Crimson;
}
.article2 {
  background-color: DarkCyan;
}
aside {
  background-color: DimGray;
}
header {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>header</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="innerwrapper">        
    <article class="article1">
      <h1>Article 1</h1>
    </article>
    <aside class="aside1">
      <h1>aside 1</h1>
    </aside>
    <article class="article2">
      <h1>Article 2</h1>
    </article>
    <aside class="aside2">
      <h1>aside 2</h1>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying to achieve it with flexbox, but it might not be possible?

Comment: Oh, one problem: I see you changed the order of the html. I don't want to change the order of the html.

Comment: @klaasjansen Sometimes you have to change to order of the html, whether you want it or not, still, will update my answer with a 2:nd sample

Comment: @klaasjansen Updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't want a fixed height either.

Comment: @klaasjansen Then my first sample solve that ... if you want to go with `flexbox` only, you'll need a script

Comment: I think I have created a problem that cannot be solved without changing the html and using floats, but these answers are not my solution.

Comment: @klaasjansen I updated my answer ... it does now cover all aspects based on the given requirements

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:
[Making two adjacent elements behave like a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383140/making-two-adjacent-elements-behave-like-a-single-element)

Potential solutions so far are (for the desktop layout):

- Use floats instead of flexbox
- Use grid design instead of flexbox (not supported in IE)
- There is a "break-after" CSS property but it's only supported in Firefox
- Add a wrapper element around the grouped elements.

Comment: With the given question here, your point 2-4 won't help since the user asked for Flexbox (no Grid), can't wrap them (not possible to stack as shown in image) and can't use "break-after" (only reach 10% of users). The point 1 I already answered with, which is today the best solution to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes I also wanted to use Flexbox, however it looks like there is no realistic way with Flexbox at the moment. And by the way, if we follow your logic, point won't help either because the user asked for Flexbox.

Comment: Exactly, hence I stated that in the first line in my answer. May I ask you to replay on the comments I posted at your own question.