# Making two adjacent elements behave like a single element

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Is it possible to make two adjacent elements behave like a single element, in a flexbox layout?

Say this is my markup:

```
<div class="flex-container">
   <div>Flower</div>
   <div>Tree</div>
   <div>Bee</div>
</div>
```

This is what I want on desktop:

```
|        |           |
|        |  Flower   |
|  Tree  |___________|
|        |           |
|        |   Bee     |
|        |           |
```

And on mobile:

```
| Flower |
|________| 
|        |
|  Tree  |
|________| 
|        |
|  Bee   |
```

So if I could combine Flower and Bee into a single flex column on desktop, it would be nice.

I could probably use a float but I'm already using a flex grid.

This is a page with variable content, I would want the content to grow vertically, and for a vertical scrollbar to appear on the page, if it goes beyond the viewport.

There is no height set on any of the boxes.

I am already using Flexbox for the grid and would not want to add any wrappers.

Comment: It is possible if you can set fixed height on flex container.

Comment: @G-Cyr Thank you, it looks like an acceptable answer. Would you like to propose an answer based on this comment? I am just curious about one thing; would you happen to know why `.flex div:nth-child(2) { min-height: 100vh }` works but not `height: 100vh`?

Comment: @G-Cyr actually it doesn't work as it is for my use case, because the height of "Flower" is variable - it will only contain the page title.
I'm trying to tinker with it, I think something can be built on it.
It's the closest answer so far - unless I decide to ignore IE.

Comment: @G-Cyr Another problem that I encountered is that when the content is too high, vertically, instead of scrolling, it pops into a 3rd column: https://codepen.io/rolfen/pen/bYLqKa 
I guess I'll just have to introduce some additional HTML elements.

Comment: ?? funny, my earlier comment is not there anymore  ? ... actually the best is the grid system but unfortunately not cross browser yet :) .  I forked https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EboBwL  including float on the switch, it might work a little better .... : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pdaVOO .

Comment: @G-Cyr Thank you, it looks like what I want! I'll see if I can integrate that with the flex grid that I'm using. I wanted to use flexbox but I guess there is no reasonable way with that.

Comment: @G-Cyr Forked your example into a minimal CSS example: https://codepen.io/rolfen/pen/LOQgPN

Comment: A question here is, which of the left/right column in desktop layout should control height. Why I ask is, when using float is very hacky to enable equal heights between the two.

Comment: Also, since creating this layout is quite simple as long as there is no content (here with Flexbox alone, [codepen sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVqeqx)), what should happen with each item when the content is too big to fit? ... scroll inside each, scroll per column, scroll all, wrap ?

Comment: @LGSon this is a page with variable content, so I would want the content to grow vertically, and for a vertical scrollbar to appear on the page, if it goes beyond the viewport. The boxes should shrink vertically to fit the content, no minimum height is required on any of them. In the real wold, "Tree" contains a photo and some buttons, Flower an H1, and Bee contains paragraphs. On mobile, I just want the title (Flower) to appear above all else, which is easy with Flexbox. I am already using Flexbox for the grid and want to have the title and text in the same column without adding wrappers.

Comment: @LGSon, ideally, the tallest column would determine the height of the whole thing.

Comment: Merged my here given answer with the answer at the dupe, and also voted to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with CSS grid layout. using `grid-template-columns` and `media-queries`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.container div {
  background: gray;
}

.container div:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 /3;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .container div:nth-of-type(2) {
    grid-row: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Flower</div>
  <div>Tree</div>
  <div>Bee</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is good to know! I was using grid layout but moved to flexbox because of IE.