# Flexbox layout - sharing the column without JS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make a holygrail-like layout as following:

[image: flexbox layout fullscreen]

Which will turn into the following on a small screen:

[image: flexbox layout small screen]

Is there a CSS way to do it, without the JS hacks?

Comment: An yet another possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790378/css-flexbox-group-2-flex-items?rq=1

Comment: And yet another link to a question without an accepted answer. Maybe we can find an answer this time and keep linking to this question in the future? :)

Comment: Just because an answer does not have an accept, doesn't mean it can't be linked to, as long as the linked answer(s) have a solution :)

Comment: I added 2 more dupe links, and this one might be exactly what you look for  ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883549/how-to-reorder-divs-using-flex-box/45883966#45883966

Comment: The one with the float ( https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pdaVOO ) seems to be the closest, but then it it setting fixed heights. I guess there is yet no elegant solution for this. The answer below might develop into one, if we add a fallback for the grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** if you set a `fixed` `height` for the *flex-container*, e.g.: `100vh`, but in this particular case the prefered way of doing it is with the ***Grid***:

```css
body {margin: 0}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* makes two columns, can also use 50% 50%, repeat(2, 1fr) or repeat(2, 50%), fr stands for fractions */
  grid-auto-rows: 150px; /* adjust or don't use at all, not mandatory */
  grid-gap: 5px 0; /* adjust, atm. 5px vertical gap, 0px horizontal */
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#container > div:nth-child(2) { /* can also use :nth-of-type(2) */
  grid-column: 1; /* puts the blue one in the left column */
  grid-row: 1/3; /* span two rows */
}

@media (max-width: 568px) { /* adjust to your needs */
  #container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; /* makes one column, can also use 100% */
    grid-gap: 0;
  }
  #container > div:nth-child(2) {
    grid-row: 2; /* puts it back where it belongs */
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="background: green">1</div>
  <div style="background: blue">2</div>
  <div style="background: red">3</div>
</div>
```

Alternative with the *positioning*:

```css
body {margin: 0}

#container {
  position: relative; /* needs to be on the parent */
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#container > div {
  position: absolute; /* needs to be on the children */
}

#container > div:first-child {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 147.5px; /* -2.5px for the vertical gap */
}

#container > div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}

#container > div:nth-child(3) { /* can also use the :last-child */
  top: 152.5px; /* height of the :first-child + 5px */
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 147.5px; /* -2.5px for the vertical gap */
}

@media (max-width: 568px) {
  #container > div {position: static}
  #container > div:first-child,
  #container > div:nth-child(2),
  #container > div:nth-child(3) {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="background: green">1</div>
  <div style="background: blue">2</div>
  <div style="background: red">3</div>
</div>
```